# Convergence of functions with different domain

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

*Question:* Is there a concept of convergence for functions $f_n: D_n \rightarrow X$ with different domains to a function $f: D \rightarrow X$?

I know concepts like [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) or [almost everywhere convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence#Almost_everywhere_convergence) but they require that all functions $f_n$ and their limit $f$ share the same domain...

*Example:* Take $D_n = \{ \tfrac kn : 0 \le k \le n, k \in \mathbb N \}$. Let $f_n$ be defined via

$$f_n : D_n \rightarrow \mathbb R: \tfrac kn \rightarrow \tfrac kn + \tfrac 1n$$

The limit I have in mind would be $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto x$.

I guess, if one requires from the limit to be continuous, the above limit $f$ is unique. But I'm not sure, because I do not know which concept of limit I can apply...

Comment: If all the $D_n$ are subspaces of $D$, with some condition like for any $N$, the union $\bigcup_{n>N}D_n =D$, then it does make some sense to ask about convergence. Going into a rigorous definition might take some work, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory of stochastic processes, one can characterize a process by a linear operator $\mathcal A$ acting on the continuous functions defined over the state space of the process. Such operator may not be defined for any function, so in fact it comes with its own domain of definition and strictly speaking we need to talk about a pair $(\mathcal A,D)$. Now, when it comes to the convergence of stochastic processes in distribution, we can show that by showing that $\mathcal A_n\to \mathcal A$ and $D_n\to D$. I guess a similar procedure may be of use in semigroup theory in general.

See for example [Theorem 4.1 here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176988499): there in condition $(4.3)$ we require that any element of a limiting domain $x\in D$ must be a limit of a sequence $x_n\in D_n$.

A similar approach can be used in your example: let's say that $(f_n,D_n) \to (f,D)$ if

> for any $x\in D = [0,1]$ there exists a sequence $x_n\in D_n$ s.t. $x_n\to x$ and $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$

which is indeed the case. Now, the question would be: how useful is such definition of limits in applications we are bearing in mind when coming up with it.

Comment: The name of this type of convergence is "convergence of stochastic process in distribution"?

Comment: @tampis: no, this kind of convergence of extended generators and their domains *implies* convergence of stochastic processes in distribution. I don't know whether the convergence of extended generators and their domains has a special name.

Comment: Okay, thx for your answer!